# Search and Update XML using multiple condition using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

```
<Students>
  <Student Name="John">
    <Subject SubId="123" Content="History minor subject" Enrolled="true" Percentage="0"/>
    <Subject SubId="146" Content="Math major Subject"  Enrolled="true" Percentage="0"/>
  </Student>
  <Student Name="Jim">
    <Subject SubId="564" Content="physics medium subject" Enrolled="true" Percentage="0"/>
    <Subject SubId="324" Content="Chem small subject" Enrolled="true" Percentage="0"/>
  </Student>
<Students>
```

Problem 1 -  I want to search if the person name content John and content has "major" -- > return the Xelememt , I am trying with below query but it is not working for me.

String studentToSearch = "John" and  string contentToSearch = "major"

```
    IEnumerable<XElement> student = from st in rootElement.Descendants("Students").Elements("Student")
                                             where st.Attribute("Name").Value.ToString() == studentToSearch && st.Element("Subject").Attribute("Content").Value.ToString().Contains(contentToSearch)
                                             select st;
```

Problem 2 - I want to search if the person name content John and content has "major", if the percentage for that find it "0"-- > then update it to "80" percentage. Trying with below query

```
  rootElement.Elements("Students")
                            .Where(x=> x.Element("Student").Value == studentToSearch)
                            .Where(a => a.Element("Subject").Attributes("Content").ToString().Contains(contentToSearch) && a.Element("Subject").Attribute("Percentage").Value == "0").FirstOrDefault()
                            .SetAttributeValue("Percentage", 80);
```

Any suggestion will be helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just deserialize the xml?  You need to use SelectMany.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Students));
            Students students = (Students)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            var johnMajor = students.Student.SelectMany(x => x.Subject.Where(y => y.Content.Contains("major")).Select(z => new { name = x.Name, Subject = z })).FirstOrDefault();
            if (johnMajor.Subject.Percentage == 0) johnMajor.Subject.Percentage = 80;
        }
    }
    public class Students
    {
        [XmlElement()]
        public List<Student> Student { get; set; }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public List<Subject> Subject { get; set; }
    }
    public class Subject
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int SubId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Content { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public Boolean Enrolled { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int Percentage { get; set; }
    }
}
```